# Refreshing the page after navigating to a screen takes me back to the main navigator

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am using expo for web, and using react-navigation for navigating between screens
whenever I save any new updates to my code the nav taking me back to the fist navigator, I did try to use expo-router but I found it very complicated and I couldn't migrate
I was trying to presist the state as per react-navigation docs so keep url path the same but with no change to success

```
  const PERSISTENCE_KEY = "NAVIGATION_STATE_V1"; 
    
    const AppNavigator = () => {
      const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);
      const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState();
    
      const prefix = Linking.createURL("myapp://");
    
      const config = {
        screens: {
          Main: {
            path: "main",
            screens: {
              Intro: "intro",
              Drawer: {
                path: "drawer",
                screens: {
                  Home: "home",
                  Profile: "profile",
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      };
    
      const linking = {
        prefixes: [prefix], // Replace with your app's actual prefixes
        config,
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const restoreState = async () => {
          try {
            const initialUrl = await Linking.getInitialURL();
    
            console.log(initialUrl);
    
            if (Platform.OS !== "web" && initialUrl == null) {
              // Only restore state if there's no deep link and we're not on web
              const savedStateString = await AsyncStorage.getItem(PERSISTENCE_KEY);
              const state = savedStateString
                ? JSON.parse(savedStateString)
                : undefined;
    
              if (state !== undefined) {
                setInitialState(state);
              }
            }
          } finally {
            setIsReady(true);
          }
        };
    
        if (!isReady) {
          restoreState();
        }
      }, [isReady]);
    
      if (!isReady) {
        return null;
      }
    
      console.log(initialState);
    
      if (!isReady) {
        return <ActivityIndicator />;
      }
    
      return (
        <NavigationContainer
          onStateChange={(state) => {
            console.log(state);
            AsyncStorage.setItem(PERSISTENCE_KEY, JSON.stringify(state));
          }}
          linking={linking}
          initialState={initialState}
        >
          <FullAppNavigator />
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    };
    
    export default AppNavigator;
```

And in App.js

```
export default function App(props) {
  const navigationContext = {};

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <NavigationContext.Provider value={navigationContext}>
          <AppNavigator />
        </NavigationContext.Provider>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}
```

so, I have two issues

1. Getting me back to the main screen everytime I am saving